# jquery 1.4.1 change() on textarea not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, textarea, onchange

So my jquery (1.4.1) code is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $("#Pattern").focus();  
    $("textarea").change(function () { Match(); });  
    ...  
    var Match = function () {
             ...
          };  
  })
```

Pattern is a textarea.
And all works fine everywhere - except IE 8. And behavior of IE 8 is weird - it doesn't work sometimes for the first time and seems to work later. By not working I mean when I type something in textarea and lose focus - Match function is not called.
I looked around but all I tried was in vain.

**EDIT: solution**

So, nothing worked and I had to do it by hand using .focusout event

```
    var previousPattern = '';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Pattern").focus();
        $("#Pattern").focusout(
                function () {
                   if ($("#Pattern").val() != previousPattern) {
                      previousPattern = $("#Pattern").val();
                      Match();
                   }
                });
       ...
    }
```

And now it works as expected.

Comment: Note: You don't need the anonymous function just to call a function, just use: `$("textarea").change(Match);`.

Comment: [can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/Vsnmm/) please give more code so we can see what might be causing this..

Comment: the whole thing is here: [rextester](http://rextester.com)

Comment: yep saw the problem now couldn't find anything unusual in the code.. try adding `alert("match");` as the first line of the function maybe it's getting executed and fails before changing the text?

Comment: tried, but the function is not called

Answer (score 0):

Twitter seems to use "input" and "change" - it's non-[standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents).
Try binding the element via [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and check, [if it is really bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106).

Comment: didn't work. Looks like change() is just a shortcut for this.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents